# Wordpress hiding posts without content on custom taxonomy query. How to solve?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, tax-query

I have a custom taxonomy query for a custom post type with the following code:

```
$args = array(
   'post-type' => 'network-partners',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
    array(
      array(
         'taxonomy' => 'network-partner-type',
         'field' => 'slug',
         'terms' => $current_term
     )
);
```

Each of the queried posts have a title, a thumbnail, ... but not every post has a content. WordPress does not show any posts which have an empty content.

Why? Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: There's nothing there to prevent content-less posts from showing. You need to show your output code.

Comment: The WP Query objects' posts simply contain the posts which have a content. I have gone through the whole query object. Also the found_posts property contains the number of posts WITH content. Is this a bug?

Comment: Actually, your query have to show all the posts, with or without content. 
Problem could be in query itself...

I see that you have no operator in your code "'operator' => 'IN'" 
and it could depend on what you have in $terms variable.